# pgAdmin: Casting null JSONB to JSON returns connection closed

Tags: json, postgresql, type-conversion, jsonb, pgadmin

I was testing out some basic operations while working on a query to perform operations on a JSON column.
When I ran this query:

```
SELECT NULL::jsonb::json
```

I received the following error message: *`Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed.`*

The server is alive and well, any other query works but anything that revolves around this particular type cast seems to be "crashing" the parser/planner/server.
Any explanation on why this particular query triggers this behaviour?

I am currently running PostgreSQL 9.6.12 and running queries with pgAdmin 4.0 4.6

Comment: I have tried this on 9.6.11 and 9.6.13 and cannot reproduce it. Is there anything logged on the server side.

Comment: Are there any extension installed (`\dx`)?

Comment: I have these extensions installed: `pg_trgm, pgcrypto, plpgsql`.
The log on the server side just reads: `LOG:  statement: SELECT NULL::jsonb::json
LOG:  statement: SELECT oid, format_type(oid, NULL) AS typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid IN (114) ORDER BY oid;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing this in several different ways I have found out that this is actually a bug in [pgAdmin 4.6](https://www.pgadmin.org/)
I have created a bug on their bug tracker and should hopefully be solve with the next version.